# How can ship crew walk in USS Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, physics, artificial-gravity

Has there been a scientific explanation for ship crew walking in spaceships in Star Trek? I know rotating stations can create artifical gravity but USS Enterprise does not rotate, at least not enough to create a centrifuge.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity

Comment: It's used so often in Sci-fi that it can be considered a trope: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtificialGravity

Comment: Scientific? No. Pseudo-Scientific? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Even though you could probably find an answer easily enough, I gave you a +1 for making me think about it. I always took it for granted.

Comment: @Omegacron I did try to find an answer and surprisingly failed. All I found was movie reviews, series plots etc.

Comment: Do do the crew of the Enterprise walk? Left foot, right foot, repeat.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite tried that with no gravity, doesn't look as cool.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Star Trek TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) (considered a canon source of info about the Star Trek Universe) contains a wealth of Treknobabble explanation regarding the presence of gravity aboard ship. In short, the technology is very similar to that of the Tractor beam;  a small device buried below the deck plating emits gravitons which then attract anything impacted by the particles:

> *The general planform of the Galaxy class starship returns to a more
>   natural existence in that people are free to move about on planar
>   surfaces with a constant gravity holding them to the deck. Aboard the
>   starship, **this is accomplished through the use of a network of small
>   gravity generators**. The network is divided into four regions, two
>   within the Saucer Module and two within the Battle Section. All four
>   work to maintain the proper sense of "down," and are also actively
>   tied to the inertial damping field system to minimize motion shock
>   during flight. The two Saucer Module gravity networks each support 400
>   generators; those in the Battle Section each support 200. Fields
>   overlap slightly between devices, but this is barely noticeable. The
>   gravity field itself is created by a controlled stream of gravitons,
>   much like those produced by the tractor beam. In fact, the basic
>   physics is the same.*
>
> *Power from the electro plasma system (EPS) is channeled into a hollow
>   chamber of anicium titanide 454, a sealed cylinder measuring 50 cm in
>   diameter by 25 cm high. Suspended in the center of the cylinder, in
>   pressurized chrylon gas, is a superconducting stator of thoronium
>   arkenide. The stator, once set to a rotational rate above 125,540 rpm,
>   generates a graviton field with a short lifetime, on the order of a
>   few picoseconds. This decay time necessitates the addition of the
>   second layer of generators beyond 30 meters distance. The field is
>   gentle enough to allow natural walking without a gravity gradient from
>   head to foot, long a problem in brute-force physical centripetal
>   systems.*

The persistence of power within the gravity generation system also explains why everything doesn't float off when the power goes out...

> *The superconducting stator remains suspended from the time of
>   manufacture, and requires only an occasional synchronizing energy
>   pulse from the EPS, normally once each sixty minutes.*

[image]

Comment: This seems more elaborate and on spot for my question. Marked it as accepted answer instead. Thanks Richard. Thanks to HorusKol too.

Comment: Good answer, Richard. That also explains how gravity can be "lost" on one deck but working everywhere else.

Comment: Just going to support this and say it matches what's in the tech manual given to writers for ST:TNG.

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty much ignored throughout most of the series, but there are a few times where the use of artificial gravity is mentioned, or fails:

- There is the malfunctioning anti-gravity sled in *[Hollow Pursuits](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hollow_Pursuits_(episode))*;
- There's configurable artificial gravity on Deep Space Nine *[Melora](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Melora_(episode))*;
- When visiting *[Empok Nor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Empok_Nor_(episode))*, the engineering team have to restore gravity;
- And then there's *[Star Trek: VI](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country)*.

Actually, there's quite a few more examples: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity.

About all we know, technically, is that there were gravity generators which feed gravity plating, and that's pretty much it.